# Убрать элемент с foreach если его свойство == свойству другого

Tags: php, массивы, объекты, foreach

Есть массив товаров, где каждый товар представлен как обьект со свойствами (напр. `->id`, `->name`, `->price` и т.д.). При выводе товаров на странице через foreach бывают случаи когда выводятся два одинаковых товара с одинаковыми `->id`. Почему так выяснять не будем, это Virtuemart, кажется проще в самом foreach'e дубликат убрать и оставить только один товар с тем же `->id`, но не знаю как именно это сделать. Т.е. нужно что то на подобии:

```
foreach($products as $product) {
    if($product->id == $product->id) {
        echo ... // вывести только один а второй такой же убрать
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = Array();    
foreach($products as $product) {
    $html[$product->id] = ''.$product->price.'';
}

echo join("", $html);
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо запоминать пройденные product_id во временном массиве.
Для массивов это выглядит так:

```
$products = array(
    array("id_product" => 1, "name"=> "text1"),
    array("id_product" => 2, "name"=> "text2"),
    array("id_product" => 1, "name"=> "text3"),
    array("id_product" => 1, "name"=> "text4")
);
$id = array();
foreach($products as &$product) {
    if (in_array($product["id_product"],$id)) unset($product);
    array_push($id,$product["id_product"]);
    print "<br>".$product["id_product"]." ".$product["name"];       
}
```

Результат:

```
1 text1
2 text2
```

Answer (score 0):

Берём колекцию product смотрим где формируеться и ставим в запросе на выборку из базы свойство distinct что бы удалить дубликаты, зачем кастыли, как будете объяснять что общее количество продуктов 10 а вывелось 5, найдено 15 а выводиться 10, и т.д.